How to use the value from a variable as the name of a parameter to set
There is a method that uses *kwargs and I am trying to pass through attributes of an object.
My current code looks something like this:
user = User(username="User", password="Password")
attr = "username"

session.execute(select(User).filter_by(attr=getattr(user, attr))).scalar_one()

I am able to use getattr() to get the value of an attribute but unure how to use the value of attr to be used.
I have attempted just using attr as the parameter name and the it was responded with User does not contain property attr
What I am hoping for is when I change attr to password it will filter using password as the parameter and the value to use.
I have googled different ways of phrasing my question but I kept getting lead to Function parameter name in variable in python. The answers provided there do not answer my question, unless I am misinterpreting the question and answers.

session.execute(select(User).filter_by(**{attr: getattr(user, attr)})).scalar_one()

python_user's comment was session.execute(select(User).filter_by(**{attr: getattr(user, attr)})).scalar_one()
The **{attr: getattr(user, attr)} as the parameter worked!

getattr() requires a string for the attribute name. But you can easily solve this by using an f-string:
getattr(user, f'{attr}')

will do the job

i think that what op wants is the filter_by clause to be dynamic

Yes, you're right. But I would say that part is solved by the answer already mentioned in the question
